# Not getting virtual collection data on the client side

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a class in my ASP.NET Core Web API. I am using EF Core to load the data.

```
var dataOutPut =  await _context.CompanyMasters
                                .Include(x => x.CompanyLicenseTypeDetails)
                                .AsNoTracking()
                                .Where(x => x.CompanyId == 45)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Data is loading without any issue on the server. Getting company details and associated `CompanyLicenseTypeDetail` collection. I confirmed with swagger and postman.

But when I tried to get this data in a Blazor wasm client, I am getting company detail but I'm not getting list of `CompanyLicenseTypeDetail`. It's showing empty on the client.

This is my class:

```
public partial class CompanyMaster
{
    public decimal CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; } = null!;

    public  virtual ICollection<CompanyLicenseTypeDetail> CompanyLicenseTypeDetails { get; } = new List<CompanyLicenseTypeDetail>();
}
```

And this my API call on client side

```
var result = await _http.Client.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<CompanyMaster>>($"api/Company/Company/{companyId}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `set;` to your `CompanyLicenseTypeDetails` property

```
public  virtual ICollection<CompanyLicenseTypeDetail> CompanyLicenseTypeDetails { get; set;} = new List<CompanyLicenseTypeDetail>();
```

Then you can get  list of `CompanyLicenseTypeDetail` normally.